# Regex to identify a word containing spaces

Tags: regex

I Need to identify a string in a text and replace it with null string. Problem is, it is not always present as a word itself. There will be space character present between each letter or set of letters. For example:

For word "Decent", I may face the following values.
D ec ent,
De ce nt,
De ce n t .

Is there a way to identify these strings using "Decent" word as input with any regular expression?
I am very new to regular expressions. Please help!!

TIA!

Comment: What language are you using?  I would say avoid a regex here, if you can.

Comment: Hope that this is not your idea of censoring.

Comment: I am using vb.net. I faced this problem while parsing a PDF document!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\bD\s*e\s*c\s*e\s*n\s*t\s*
```

so you match `D ec    ent, De ce nt, De ce n t, decent Decent`

but not `blade centimeter`

Answer (score 1):

If you use

'D ?e ?c ?e ?n ?t ?'

it will match the word with extra spaces

Comment: `\b` is recommended here, to prevent the case of cutting off half the end of some word and half the beginning of another word.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `"D\s*e\s*c\s*e\s*n\s*t"` will do it. Each letter is followed by zero or more spaces. Actually `\s` is "whitespace characters." You could replace `\s*` with `*` (space followed by an asterisk) if you just want literal spaces.

Answer (score 0):

first a bit of code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class WordsWithSpaces {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "Descent D escent De s  cent desce nd";
        String word = "descent";
        String pattern = "";
        for(int i=0; i<word.length();i++) {
            pattern = pattern+word.charAt(i)+"\\s*";
        }
        System.err.println("pattern is: "+pattern);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
        while(m.find()) {
            String found = test.substring(m.start(),m.end());
            System.err.println(found+" matches");
        }


    }

}
```

now for the explanation: \s is a character class for whitespace. this includes spaces and tabs and (possibly) linebreaks. in this piece of code, i take every character of the word i am looking for, and append "\s", with "*" meaning 0 or mor occurences.

also, to avoid it being case sensitive, i set the  CASE_INSENSITIVE flag on the pattern.

character classes may not have the same name in your programming language of choice, but there should be one for whitespace. check your documentation.

Comment: `\s` does include line break `\n`, `\r`.

Comment: No. It always match a new line, flag doesn't have any effect on `\s`. `MULTILINE` only affects the meaning of `^` and `$`.